# exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' error in exception.log file

Tags: magento-1.9, log, email-scheduler

I am trying to send Abandoned cart emails, but emails are not delivering at the scheduled time. even not sending after scheduled time.

cron job is working fine & other emails like welcome , order emails are working fine.

**exception.log**

```
exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Unable to Connect to
 ssl://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443. Error #110: Connection timed out' 
 in /lib/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /lib/Zend/Http/Client.php(1065): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->connect('email.us-east-1...', 443, true)
#1 /app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/lib/AmazonSES.php(105): Zend_Http_Client->request('POST')
#2 /lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): App_Mail_Transport_AmazonSES->_sendMail()
#3 /lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#4 /app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php(132): Zend_Mail->send(Object(App_Mail_Transport_AmazonSES))
#5 /app/code/local/Mirasvit/Email/Model/Queue.php(186): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template->send('kidsdial1@gmail...', 'dyhxnnx nnx', Array)
#6 /app/code/local/Mirasvit/Email/Model/Trigger.php(231): Mirasvit_Email_Model_Queue->send()
#7 /app/code/local/Mirasvit/Email/Model/Trigger.php(302): Mirasvit_Email_Model_Trigger->triggerEvent(Object(Mirasvit_Email_Model_Event), true)
#8 /app/code/local/Mirasvit/Email/controllers/Adminhtml/TriggerController.php(83): Mirasvit_Email_Model_Trigger->sendTest('kidsdial1@gmail...')
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mirasvit_Email_Adminhtml_TriggerController->saveAction()
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

i followed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846310/unable-to-connect-to-ssl) & added line : **extension=php_openssl.dll** in php.ini file

Comment: i found solution, i will post it soon.....

Comment: Same here :P Please add an short answer to accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem raised just because of an extension, we need to create **trigger** and we need to set the **time** of Delivering abandoned cart email in Trigger. Once if customer Abandoned the cart & **Mail** will be in **Queue** and it will deliver at the time that we set in Trigger. In this case before delivering the email if we delete the Trigger, this issue i posted in question will happen....